# How can I get the Bluetooth MAC address of my own android device through code?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, mac-address

I am developing an application in which I require to send my Bluetooth MAC address to the server and also I am searching for the nearby Bluetooth devices and sending the list of their Bluetooth MAC address to the server. On the server end I use this information to filter out the android devices that I need from the other devices. But I can not find a way to find out the Bluetooth MAC address of my own device but I can see the MAC addresses of the other devices.
Can anyone please help me with this issue? If you are not able to tell how to get the MAC address can you suggest some other method by which I can do this. I am basically trying to create a contact tracing application which works via Bluetooth.

Comment: MAC addresses generally [are not available on modern versions of Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-addresses) for privacy reasons. Note that [the Apple/Google contact tracing system](https://www.apple.com/covid19/contacttracing/) does not appear to rely upon MAC addresses.

Comment: The above comment is correct, trying to read the local Bluetooth MAC will result in 02:00:00:00:00:00, which tells you nothing. In addition, even though you can see nearby Bluetooth MAC addresses, you should know that most phones randomize their publicly visible MAC addresses and they change pretty frequently.  This means those MAC addresses will not help you either.

Comment: My application is going to be used in a limited area like in a factory. Anyways then how can I identify nearby devices on the server. Any ideas? I need some unique identification that a phone can send to the server and also see of the other devices.